# Fab button not working on a scroll view in react native

Tags: floating-action-button, react-native-scrollview, react-native-paper

Fab button is not working on a scroll view. I am using FAB from react-native-paper and the icon is displayed but when i press fab button, its not working. As an alternative, i tried to make a sticky button which sticks to the bottom when i use scroll view, but the button is displayed after the scrollview content and is not fixed at the bottom of our screen. It also fails.

My code is like :

```
<View>
   <FAB style={{position:'absolute',right:0,bottom:0}}/>
   <ScrollView></ScrollView>
</View>
```

Answer (score 6):

Rendering `Fab` below the `ScrollView` should work.

```
<ScrollView />
<Fab />
```

Answer (score 3):

Fab needs to be above all the components.
Put it inside `<Portal>` tag
https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/portal.html

Comment: This solved a similar problem I have been having with IconButton. thank you.

Comment: This caused an issue. while navigating Fab moves a bit